# If $z$ is not divisible by $r$, where $r$ is a prime of the form $(4n+3)$, then there exists an integer $z_{1}$ such that $zz_{1} \equiv 1 (mod r) $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I was reading Diophantine Analysis (*Robert Carmichael*), and on Page No.-34 of the book, it says :

If $z$ is not divisible by $r$, where $r$ is a prime of the form (4n+3), then there exists an integer $z_{1}$ such that $zz_{1} \equiv 1 mod r $.

I tried and couldn't prove this. If anyone could help me with the proof, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The condition on the form of $r$ is irrelevant; if $(z, r) = 1$ then there exist integers $z_1, z_2$ such that $zz_1 + rz_2 = 1$ (by the Euclidean algorithm), so $zz_1 \equiv 1 \bmod r$.

Comment: Perhaps what is confusing is that $r$ is specified as a prime of the form $4n+3$; this is a bit of a red herring, since for *any* two relatively prime numbers $z$ and $r$, there exist integers $z_1$ and $z_2$ for which $zz_1 + rz_2 = 1$. Reduced modulo $r$, that last equation becomes the one about which you ask.

Comment: gr8 thanks!, hard for myself to believe that I missed something this obvious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $r$ is prime and $r\nmid z$, $\gcd(r,z)=1$. Therefore, there are integers $z_1$ and $n$ such that $rn+zz_1=1$. In particular, $zz_1\equiv1\pmod r$.

Answer (score 0):

**A Fun Overkilling Solution**

Let $q\in\{1,2,\ldots,r-1\}=:[r-1]$ be the remainder of $z$ when divided by $r$.  Using Wilson's Theorem, we have
$$z\,\prod_{j\in[r-1]\setminus\{q\}}\equiv q\,\prod_{j\in[r-1]\setminus \{q\}} j=(r-1)!\equiv-1\pmod{r}\,.$$
Therefore, $z_1:=-\prod_{j\in[r-1]\setminus\{q\}}\,j$ will work, albeit being quite inefficient to determine.

Comment: great solution!,really innovative!!